# In xterm, what is "Icon Name"?

Tags: gnome-terminal, xterm

Running in xterm (or gnome-terminal) the following command sets the [so-called](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Controls) "Icon Name":

```
echo -en "\e]1;some_value\a"
```

What does this do?

Note that it is possible to set both "Window Title" and "Icon Name" to the same value with the same command, so I don't understand how "Icon Name" could be a path to, say, an image.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A long time ago, there was a window manager called twm—actually, it still exists and runs perfectly well. Instead of minimizing a window to a bar at the bottom of the screen (or similar) like MS Windows, Mac OS X, and many modern window managers, it shrunk them to labeled icons ("iconfify").

The [Wikipedia twm article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twm) has some nice pictures, such as:

[image: Screenshot from TWM]

The window title is what goes in the titlebar (e.g., the "Calculator" or "xterm"). The icon name is what goes under the icon when iconified (the "xclock"). Modern window managers probably all ignore the icon name because they don't use the icon UI.

A full description of both can be [found in the ICCCM](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#WM_NAME).

Comment: Windows 3 used to iconify like that.

Answer (score 5):

I'll talk about `xterm` here: it's an old piece of software and much of its terminology is now outdated. In `man xterm` it says:

> ```
>     iconName (class IconName) 
>             Specifies a label for xterm when
>             iconified.  Xterm provides no default value; some
>             window managers may assume the application name, e.g.,
>             "xterm"
>
>             Setting the iconName resource sets the icon label
>             unless overridden by zIconBeep or the control sequences
>             which change the window and icon labels.
> ```

That means that `iconName` must not be an icon image, it's just a label that's given to `xterm` window when it's iconified. It can be also set using `-n` option:

> ```
> -n string
>         This option specifies the icon name for xterm's windows.  It
>         is shorthand for specifying the "iconName" resource.  Note
>         that this is not the same as the toolkit option -name (see
>         below).  The default icon name is the application name.
> ```

After starting `xterm` like this, with a `title` != `iconName` I still can't see `ICON` string being shown after iconifying `xterm` window (Alt-F9 in `fluxbox`):

```
$ xterm -n ICON -T a-new-title
```

Digging further through `xterm` manpage one finds (`**` mine):

> ```
>    activeIcon (class ActiveIcon) 
>            Specifies whether or not active
>            icon windows are to be used when the xterm window is
>            iconified, if this feature is compiled into xterm.  The
>            active icon is a miniature representation of the
>            content of the window and will update as the content
>            changes.  Not all window managers necessarily support
>            application icon windows.  Some window managers will
>            allow you to enter keystrokes into the active icon
>            window.  The default is "default".
>
>            Xterm accepts either a keyword (ignoring case) or the
>            number shown in parentheses:
>
>            false (0)
>                   No active icon is shown.
>
>            true (1) 
>                   The active icon is shown.  If you are using
>                   twm, use this setting to enable active-icons.
>
>            default (2) 
>                   Xterm checks at startup, and shows an
>                   active icon only for window managers which it
>                   can identify and which are known to support the
>                   feature.  **These are fvwm (full support), and
>                   window maker (limited).**  A few other windows
>                   managers (such as twm and ctwm) support active
>                   icons, but do not support the exten- sions which
>                   allow xterm to identify the window manager.
> ```

`activeIcon` is probably not directly related to `iconName` feature, however it gives us a clue that icon-related features in `xterm` work correctly only with some window managers. I recommend `Xephyr` for testing one either `fvwm` or `window maker` as specified in the manpage:

```
$ Xephyr :1 -ac -screen 800x600
```

and in another terminal:

```
$ DISPLAY=:1 wmaker
```

Now let's start `xterm` inside `window maker`: right click -> `Applications` -> `Terminals` -> `xterm`. Start `xterm` with `-n` option again:

```
$ xterm -n ICON -T a-new-title
```

Right click on the title bar and choose `Miniaturize`. Now you can see that an `xterm` icon is actually labeled `ICON`. Bring it back by clicking on it and see that titlebar is `a-new-title`. The conclusion is that `iconName` feature works only with some window managers, most probably older ones. If you feel strong you can browse `window maker` source code and patch your own window manager if it doesn't support `iconName`.

BTW, for changing `xterm` icon image see this: https://superuser.com/questions/344320/how-do-i-change-the-icon-of-an-xterm.

Comment: Active icons are basically a different window state -- rather than hiding the window, it is switched to "icon" state. This is still a regular window though, and the program can draw normally, so program state can be shown in the icon if desired.